# Rotate Animation is not working on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-4.4-kitkat

I have used rotate animation for my button. its working fine on Android 5.0 and above but when tested on Android 4.4 version. its blinks and doesn't rotate. AS suggested by some others i have tried with Layer type, fill after and fill before. But nothing works. Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <rotate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="180"
    android:repeatMode="reverse">
  </rotate>
</set>

Animation mAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate);

    mAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        exchangeValues();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

      }
    });
    if (floatingActionButton != null) {
      floatingActionButton.startAnimation(mAnim);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I found the answer for my own question. I have tried setting Layer type and many of other solutions provided at different places. but some one suggested me to use ObjectAnimator and it worked for me like a charm. Here is the code

```
ObjectAnimator floatingButtonAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(floatingActionButton,
    ANIMATION_NAME, ANIMATION_STARTING_DEGREE, ANIMATION_ENDING_DEGREE);
floatingButtonAnimator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION).addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    super.onAnimationStart(animation);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
    exchangeValues();
  }
});
floatingButtonAnimator.start();
```

Comment: What is ANIMATION_NAME?

Comment: What is `ANIMATION_NAME`? What is `exchangeValues`?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an **hardware acceleration** issue: try set the `LayerType` of your `View`/`Button` to `LayerType.SOFTWARE`

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

I'll also suggest to try to slightly **increase** the animation's duration (e.g. up to 400ms).